# Why does my G1ANT software do not contain addon ocrtesseract in its addons list?

Tags: g1ant

My software do not have addon ocrtesseract in its addon list even if I try to add it manually its shows me an error which I have attached

[image]
list of addons present
[image]
Error displayed

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue in the developer version of the software. However, any expert insights would be very much appreciated.